# VB.NET How to parse and add the result into the list(of string) from json file?

Tags: vb.net, string, assets, minecraft, async-await

I'm creating a launcher for Minecraft. I have a problem, My launcher using json files to load and check files. How can I add the strings from this json (example) into the AssetsList? https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/1.8.json

My code, if it helps you to understand me (I'm using Newtonsoft.json to parse json):

The MCAssets class:

```
Public Class MCAssets
    Public hash As String
End Class
```

The list:

```
Public AssetsList As New List(Of String)
```

The funchtion to get the assets:

```
Public Async Function GetAssets() As Task
    If Not Directory.Exists(Root + "\assets\indexes") Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Root + "\assets\indexes")
    End If
    Dim client = New WebClient()
    Await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New Uri(String.Format("http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/{0}.json", AssetIndex)), String.Format(Root + "\assets\indexes\{0}.json", AssetIndex))
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(Root + "\assets\indexes\" + AssetIndex + ".json")
    Dim assets As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    Dim jsonresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(assets)
    For Each i In jsonresult("objects").Children()
        AssetsList.Add(i.ToObject(Of MCAssets).hash)
    Next
End Function
```

If you want know more about Minecraft assets, visit this:  https://github.com/tomsik68/mclauncher-api/wiki/Minecraft-1.6-resources

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the provided snippet? What does/doesn't work as expected?

Comment: And what exception would be unhandled? Could you perhaps handle it and show us a stacktrace of what's actually going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the right Uri? because, to my eyes `New "http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/" + AssetIndex + "/" + AssetIndex + ".json"` is not matched with your sample link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim assetsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(assets) 'assets is your json file
Dim allAssets = (From i In assetsObject("objects").Children() _
                 Select New MCAssets() With {.hash = i.First.Value(Of String)("hash")}).ToList()
```

By the way, there is not really a need to make a custom class. You can just add all of the hashes to a list of string like so:

```
Dim assetsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(assets)
Dim allAssets = (From i In assetsObject("objects").Children() _
                 Select i.First.Value(Of String)("hash"))
```

Comment: How can I add all assets into the assetlist? I want to add all assets into a list, then add first two letter from all assets.all.item into the path list.

Comment: By assets do you mean the name of each asset. So for example, the first one, 'realms/lang/de_DE.lang'? But you said you only want the first 2 letters, 're'. Correct?

Comment: Sory for late, the example: adhjvnkfirioskkokdmsjnaskla this is a hash example,  I want to get this from the json and then get from the list the first 2 letter and add it into another list, because this is the path, and the full hash as the filename, so the path: ad and the filename: adhjvnkfirioskkokdmsjnaskla thanks!

Comment: Easy enough just add this under the declaration of 'allAssets', `Dim assetsFileName = (allAssets.Select(Function(i) String.Concat(i.hash.Take(2))))`